# how to convert json array object to javascript array from firebase sever json?

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is format I got from Firebase

```
{
    "-KpigwmSqAYFFaWgHYZ5": {
        "name": "chomroeun",
        "password": "123",
        "phone": "093909157",
        "team": "Ekerk"
    },
    "-KpihLkWatPmYJBlVjCR": {
        "name": "hello",
        "password": "123",
        "phone": "322344",
        "team": "eer"
    },
    "-KpihrxRw_L5Z2f5Jceb": {
        "name": "visal",
        "offline_image": {
            "-KpjPf3fO8Vz1rVu-lvl": "content://com.animalmama.innov8_dealer/my_images/id_card_PP00003_20170723_192720_1055007560.jpg",
            "-KpjPjtIGjHoL_bvKF5x": "content://com.animalmama.innov8_dealer/my_images/id_card_PP00003_20170723_192720_1055007560.jpg",
            "-KpjPjtJcTAIL3PZTjX9": "content://com.animalmama.innov8_dealer/my_images/id_card_PP00003_20170723_192739_473034014.jpg"
        },
        "password": "1234",
        "phone": "069331000",
        "team": "k01"
    },
    "-KpiiPhpXxDHZd4JRYNw": {
        "name": "Hongda",
        "password": "123",
        "phone": "098776688",
        "team": "Hog"
    },
    "-KpiiX8Xf9fWHAheIJlm": {
        "name": "Hongda",
        "password": "123",
        "phone": "098776688",
        "team": "Hog"
    },
    "-KpiiixW0jRegBk6-CL2": {
        "name": "TT",
        "password": "123",
        "phone": "059544",
        "team": "dd"
    }
}
```

But what I want the format like this

```
{ "aaData": [
        [ "1", "Armand", "Warren", "56045", "Taiwan, Province of China" ],
        [ "2", "Xenos", "Salas", "71090", "Liberia" ],
        [ "3", "Virginia", "Whitaker", "62723", "Nicaragua" ],
        [ "4", "Kato", "Patrick", "97662", "Palau" ],
        [ "5", "Penelope", "Hensley", "76634", "Greenland" ],
        [ "6", "Georgia", "Erickson", "81358", "Bolivia" ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: It would help if the data in your examples matched.

Comment: How did you get the JSON from Firebase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When youre working wirh firebase , arrays not your friend.
However if you want to turn objects into  arrays you can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)  function for iterate trough root object props and return an array

```
 Object.keys(asd).map(function(a,i){
 return[i,asd[a].name,asd[a].password]
 })
```

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/iuNSHU2DuW9wzC57Gwje?p=preview)